# Open source DocBook editor

Tags: xml, xslt, editor, wysiwyg

I'm using Docbook every day but I find classical text editors unsuitable for editing long XML files with long mark names.

So, I'm looking to an open source software that can permits me to edit a Docbook file simply.

I've found some softwares (Altova, oXygen, ...) but I didn't find any open source software.

In the best case, the editor would read the DTD or the XSD and would use a user XSLT file to display dynamically the XML file and would permit to edit it graphically, but I think this software doesn't exists.

Do you have any ideas on XML editors approaching this "dream".

Comment: Off topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [DocBook Editing and Processing for Eclipse (DEP4E)](http://dep4e.sourceforge.net/) it is based on Eclipse.

**TIP:** Look at the [Quick Start Guide](http://dep4e.sourceforge.net/documentation/quick-start-guide%E2%80%8E/index%E2%80%8E.html) - Section **3. Getting Started** to get an idea.

It supports DTD and XML Schema for DocBook.